# SQL - Joining Two Tables and Sum of Column

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have a situation where I have table A that have member info and table B that has a list of transactions for the members. I need to retrieve fields from Table A with a total of the transaction column for each member.

I have struggled with the proper SQL syntax and it keeps error on me. We are using MS Reporting Services to develop this if that helps.

Table A:

```
Member ID     LName     FName    Phone
----------------------------------------------
1234          Doe       John     555-555-5555
5678          Doe       Jane     555-555-5550
```

Table B:

```
Member ID     Transaction Date     Transaction Total
----------------------------------------------------
1234          01-01-2020           120.00
1234          01-05-2020            25.00
5678          01-01-2020            50.00
5678          01-10-2020            50.00
5678          01-11-2020            25.00
1234          01-15-2020            25.00
```

Desired output:

```
Member ID:     Last Name:     First Name:     Total:
----------------------------------------------------
1234           Doe            John            170.00
5678           Doe            Jane            125.00
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for aggregation with `group by` & `sum()` :

```
select a.memberid, a.lname, a.fname, sum(b.transactiontotal) as total
from a inner join
     b
     on b.memberid = a.memberid
group by a.memberid, a.lname, a.fname;
```